# Highlight rows of my table where checkbox is checked with knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have an html table with a checkbox on first column. I would like to highlight the row where checkboxes are checked with **knockout**.

```
<table class="defaultGrid">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Check</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Things">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.selectThing " /></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4H6/1/

I don't know how to proceed. I don't want to add an extra property on my model like 'isSelected'.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely add a knockout observable to your 'Thing' that determines whether or not your tr element has a yellow background or not.

However, if you **really** don't want to add something like this to your view model, you'll have to add some logic to your *selectThing* function to handle this for you e.g.

```
self.selectThing = function(item, event) {
        $(event.target).parent().parent().addClass('selected');
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4H6/27/

```
 $(function() {
Thing = function(id, name, selected) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = id, 
    self.Name = name
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
};

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.model = {};
    self.model.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observable();
    self.model.Things = ko.observableArray(
        [
            new Thing(1, "Thing 1"),
            new Thing(2, "Thing 2"),
            new Thing(3, "Thing 3")
        ]);
    self.selectThing = function(item) {

    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

});